# syntax error on token BLANK while expected?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

I am a bit new to coding a don't understand why this has come up. Someone please help.

import java.util.Scanner;

class calculateMortgageA {
public static void main (String[]args) {

```
//create scanner 
Scanner input =new Scanner (System.in);

//prompt user to write in salaries so they can be read in while declaring the variables for the salaries
System.out.println("Enter person 1's salary:");
double salaryOne = input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("Enter person 2'a salary:");
double salaryTwo=input.nextDouble();

//calculate the mortgage 
System.out.print("The mortgage will be £" + calcmortgage(salaryOne,salaryTwo));

input.close();
```

}

public static double calcmortgage (double salaryOne, double salaryTwo) {

```
    double mortgage;

    if (salaryOne > salaryTwo)
           mortgage = 3*salaryOne + salaryTwo;
           return mortgage;

    
    else (salaryTwo > salaryOne)
           mortgage = 3*salaryTwo + salaryOne;
           return mortgage;
```

}

}

Comment: Which line gave you the error?

Comment: You will need a block, delimited with braces ( { ... } ) after the two final if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the curly braces around the blocks of the `if` and `else`:

```java
public static double calcmortgage (double salaryOne, double salaryTwo) {

    double mortgage;

    if (salaryOne > salaryTwo) { // Here
           mortgage = 3*salaryOne + salaryTwo;
           return mortgage;
    } // And here
    else (salaryTwo > salaryOne) { // And here
           mortgage = 3*salaryTwo + salaryOne;
           return mortgage;
    } // And here
}
```